# Nothing Returned for Single Character Output

Tags: python

This is supposed to be part of a function that replaces consonants with `'$'` until the `"ch"` character is reached, where it will then stop.

**Examples:**

`vowels_or_not(‘abcdeAghi’, ‘A’)` should return `‘a$$$e’`

`vowels_or_not(‘aaaaA’, ‘A’)` should return `‘aaaa’`

My issue is that it isn't doing anything if the input string is only one character long. `vowels_or_not(a, X)` should return `a` and `vowels_or_not(x, A)` should return `$`. Everything else works fine. I tried fixing it but I still don't see anything wrong with the code, but then again I'm a beginner! Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
def vowels_or_not (st, ch)
    vowels = ('a','e','i','o','u','A','E','I','O','U')
    flag = True
    a = 0
    aux = ''
    while flag is True:
        for i in range(len(st)):        
            if (st[i] == ch):
                flag = False
                break
            else:
                if (st[i] in vowels):
                    aux = aux + st[i]
                    a = a + 1
                if (st[i] not in vowels):
                    aux = aux + '$'
                    a = a + 1
    return aux
```

Comment: This isn't the actual code you're running; it is missing the `:` after the function definition, and so it won't run. Is there anything else different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is your while loop never ends if the last character in `st` isn't the same as `ch`.

But you don't really need that while loop as it is redundant, you only need the for-loop:

```
def vowels_or_not(st, ch):
    vowels = ('a','e','i','o','u','A','E','I','O','U')
    a = 0
    aux = ''
    for i in range(len(st)):
        if (st[i] == ch):
            break
        else:
            if (st[i] in vowels):
                aux = aux + st[i]
                a = a + 1
            if (st[i] not in vowels):
                aux = aux + '$'
                a = a + 1
    return aux
```

---

```
>>> vowels_or_not('a', 'X')
'a'
>>> vowels_or_not('aaaAX', 'X')
'aaaA'
>>> vowels_or_not('aaabX', 'X')
'aaa$'
```

Comment: Ha, I guess so! We just learned about while loops recently and I never used them so I figured I would do it here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your code isn't working in those cases because your `while` loop never ends. Once that `for` loop exits, the `while` loop just keeps going forever.

To fix your code, just set `flag = False` once the `for` loop ends:

```
def vowels_or_not (st, ch):
    vowels = ('a','e','i','o','u','A','E','I','O','U')
    flag = True
    a = 0
    aux = ''
    while flag is True:
        for i in range(len(st)):        
            if (st[i] == ch):
                flag = False
                break
            else:
                if (st[i] in vowels):
                    aux = aux + st[i]
                    a = a + 1
                if (st[i] not in vowels):
                    aux = aux + '$'
                    a = a + 1

        flag = False   # <-- Right here
    return aux
```

And an example:

```
>>> vowels_or_not('a', 'x')
'a'
>>> vowels_or_not('x', 'a')
'$'
```

To make your code a little better, don't use indices. Python lets you iterate over strings intuitively:

```
def vowels_or_not(word, character):
    vowels = 'aeiou'
    output = ''

    before, middle, after = word.partition(character)

    for letter in before:
        if letter.lower() in vowels:
            output += letter
        else:
            output += '$'

    return output + middle + after
```

Comment: And thanks for the tip, I'll keep that in mind for the future! I didn't learn about that yet, so I don't want to seem like I'm cheating or something :P.

Answer (score 0):

```
import functools # for python3 reduce (working under python2 too)

vowels = 'aeiouAEIOU'

def vowels_or_not (st, ch):
    return functools.reduce(lambda a,b:a+(b in vowels and b or '$'), st.partition(ch)[0],'')
```

or longer version

```
vowels = 'aeiouAEIOU'

def vowels_or_not_longer_version (st, ch):
    ret=''
    for i in st.partition(ch)[0]:
        ret+= i in vowels and i or '$'
    return ret
```